# Import data from a dBase (.dbf) file into mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, dbase

I need to import data from a legacy application into mongodb. Is there any driver that lets me read a dbf file and write it to mongodb (preferably via node.js)? I don't need to write to the dbase file, so only reading files is needed. Also, as the files are quite big, the read process should take place in chunks of records.

Comment: You are going to have to script this.  You're reading from a table and writing to a collection.

Comment: That's ok with me, but how to get access to the dbf file?

Comment: ODBC is probably your best option.  https://www.npmjs.org/package/odbc

Comment: Looks like there are a number of packages with direct `dbf` support: https://www.npmjs.org/browse/keyword/dbf.

Comment: Hm, iirc, some versions of MS Excel can open dbf files. Make a copy and try it. If they open, simply export them as CSV, which in turn can be imported to mongoDB.